# Getting a TypeError after one iteration of a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, typeerror

As mentioned in the title I am getting a `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable` when using my code.
The code runs once correctly with the information that I want but fails to run the second time using `for fare in fares`.

Error message is here:

```
File "/Users/dty2004/Desktop/AS 91373.py", line 71, in <module>
    discounted_price(destination_fare)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Code is here:

```
# Define the lists required for storing discount and discount_price
fare_auck = ["Auckland"]
fare_well = ["Wellington"]
fare_roto = ["Rotorua"]

# Make the lists into a 2D list
fares = [fare_auck, fare_well, fare_roto]

# Define the menu() function, which gives us the basic interface for 
launching functions
def menu(destination, discounted_price, discount, saver_type, 
original_price):
    print("***** Waikato Air *****")
    print("These saver fares for tomorrow only!")
    print("Destination: {}".format(destination))
    print("Discounted Price: ${:.2f}".format(discounted_price))
    print("Percentage Discount: {:.2f}%".format(discount))
    print("This fare is a: {}".format(saver_type))
    print("Original Price: ${:.2f}".format(original_price))
    print("") # Added an empty string to format the function to look nice 
consecutively

# Define the function for destination determination
def destination_determiner():
    if fares[0][0] == "Auckland":
        travel_location = "Auckland"
        fares[0].insert(0, "placeholder")
        return travel_location
    elif fares[1][0] == "Wellington":
        travel_location = "Wellington"
        fares[1].insert(0, "placeholder")
        return travel_location
    elif fares[2][0] == "Rotorua":
        travel_location = "Rotorua"
        fares[2].insert(0, "placeholder")
        return travel_location

# Define the function for determining the type of saver fare this is
def saver_type(discount):
    if discount < 20 and discount > -1:
        saver_type = "Quick Saver"
        return saver_type
    elif discount >= 20 and discount <= 50:
        saver_type = "Smart Saver"
        return saver_type
    elif discount > 50 and discount < 101:
        saver_type = "Super Saver"
        return saver_type
    else:
        print("Sorry that input is invalid")

# Define the function for determining the original_price
def original_price_calc(discount, discounted_price):
    original_price = discounted_price * (discount / 100 + 1)
    return original_price

# Define the function for getting discounted_price from user input
def discounted_price(destination):
    discounted_price = float(input("Please input the discounted price to 
{}".format(destination_fare)))
    fare.append(discounted_price)

# Define the same function for getting discount from user input
def discount(destination):
    discount = float(input("Please input the discount in percentage to 
{}".format(destination_fare)))
    fare.append(discount)

# Run the entire code, formatted into a print statement
for fare in fares:
    destination_fare = destination_determiner()
    discounted_price(destination_fare)
    discount(destination_fare)
    discounted_price = fare[2]
    discount = fare[3]
    menu(destination_fare, discounted_price, discount, saver_type(discount), 
original_price_calc(discount, discounted_price))
```

This runs once using accepted values in this example of 100 and 30:

```
Please input the discounted price to Auckland100
Please input the discount in percentage to Auckland30
***** Waikato Air *****
These saver fares for tomorrow only!
Destination: Auckland
Discounted Price: $100.00
Percentage Discount: 30.00%
This fare is a: Smart Saver
Original Price: $130.00
```

I'm unsure as to why this works the first time but not the second.
Also bear in mind I am a student and so may not have much knowledge on more advanced python commands.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're reusing names left and right.  Every variable name should refer to exactly one thing.

Answer (score 1):

You're reassigning discounted_price to a variable here:

```
# Run the entire code, formatted into a print statement
for fare in fares:
    destination_fare = destination_determiner()
    discounted_price(destination_fare) # still a function
    discount(destination_fare)
    discounted_price = fare[2] # now a float!!!!
    discount = fare[3] # same with this (overrides discount from earlier)
    menu(destination_fare, discounted_price, discount, saver_type(discount), 
original_price_calc(discount, discounted_price))
```

Rename the variable to something else

```
for fare in fares:
    destination_fare = destination_determiner()
    discounted_price(destination_fare)
    discount(destination_fare)
    discounted_price_value = fare[2]
    discount_value = fare[3]
    menu(destination_fare, discounted_price_value, discount_value, 
         saver_type(discount_value),
         original_price_calc(discount_value, discounted_price_value))
```